# Javascript stopPropagation

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning so probably the code is not the best. I tried several examples in other answers but I'm stuck here.

```
Function invisibleDiv(){  
  var invDiv = document.createElement('div');  
  var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');  
  secondDiv.setAttribute('class', 'secondDiv');
  document.body.appendChild(invDiv);
  invDiv.appendChild(secondDiv);
};
```

And I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".secondDiv", function (e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

All that is working but I'm trying to replace all my jQuery functions with pure Javascript so I tried this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var secondDiv = document.querySelector('.secondDiv').
  div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation; // Not working
    secondDiv.stopPropagation; // Not working
  }
});
```

I tried adding the event listener into the Function invisibleDiv  and I can see in DevTools the event is attached, but when clicking secondDiv still triggers the event in invisibleDiv.

I can make it work adding both divs into the html code with Display: none/block but since it works with jQuery when added dynamically I wanna know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: To tell what you're doing wrong you need to explain what you need to do first. What do you want to express with `secondDiv.stopPropagation`?

Comment: I'm appending a transparent div to the body with heigth and size 100% and, another div to the transparent div. So you can select options in the second div and when clicking outside of the second div it will trigger the event in the transparent div which will remove boths divs. But when clicking an option in the second div it propagate to the transparent div and remove boths divs. It works with Jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Based on your comments above, it seems to me that you're looking for something like this:

```
  var outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
  var inner = document.querySelector('.inner');

  outer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log("Outer clicked");
  });

 inner.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j9a0nsto/

It looks like you're not calling the function.

Functions in JavaScript are executed by using `()` brackets so your code becomes:

`e.stopPropagation();` and `secondDiv.stopPropagation();`

The call to `secondDiv.stopPropagation()` is redundant since the [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) object doesn't have that function, and needs to be removed.

Comment: Nothing as far as I know. There's no stopPropagation method on a node collection. This can be removed.

Comment: aye. I missed it the first time round in my haste to answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I tried stopPropagation(); with and without brackets but the click still propagates and I added both just as an example beacause I tried e.stopPropagation; e.stopPropagation(); seconDiv.stopPropagation; secondDiv.stopPropagation(); and even preventDefault.

Comment: We don't know what `div` is in your code example, but my guess is that you really wanted to attach the click handler to `secondDiv` rather than `div`.

Comment: Please see my update. I think this is what you're asking about.

Comment: yes thats waht I did to solve it. The problem was that i was adding both divs dynamically and then it doesnt work. So I'm concern about how to do it dynamically. I'm just tring to replace the Jquery code with javascript but I can't make it work.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the divs are added dynamically. It still works the same. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/j9a0nsto/1/

Comment: Yes you are right I tried that fiddle thing http://jsfiddle.net/zn6e91hw/ so I probably have something wrong in some other place I'm gonna recheck everything once more :/ Thanks